# Application_End Not Running

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to C#, so please bear with me.

I have a function that runs in the `Application_Start` function in the Global.asax.cs file, and this works fine when I start debugging.

But when I stop debugging, the function I have in the Application_End function doesn't seem to fire off.  I'm wondering if this has to do with debugging, or is just an error in my code.

Comment: Its quite possible your application is still running. Have you checked that your running instance of IIS Express has closed completely in your system tray? Are you hosting it in full IIS?

Comment: I'm hosting it in IIS Express, but from the looks of things, I think you are right, I don't think it is stopping.  I need to have this function execute when I stop running the function.  Do you know how I would tell it to stop?

Comment: @user3413723: are you sure you want to end it at application exit, rather than session for example? What kind of actions do you want to perform?

Comment: It's an asmx file that works with an api.  I have a "start listening" function and a "stop listening" function that need to execute on program begin and end.

Comment: @user3413723 what does it matter if it doesn't stop listening? the entire AppDomain is being torn down and will be cleaned up anyway? Does `Listen()` lock resources on the remote end of the webserivce? If so, that's probably a bad design for a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in general not a good idea to put a lot of code in Application_End that you need to rely on firing.  Consider that an ApplicationInstance is started to each thread of the work process that will be serving your application, you will run into scenarios where your Application_End will be called frequently on a busy site as traffic ebbs and flows.

You may find it easier to use a Cache object with a sliding expiration and a callback function when the object expires from Cache to ensure that your clean up code is called properly when you need it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I guess the application never ended. While you are debugging (using Cassandra or IIS Express) or running an installation on IIS itself the application doesn't end when your debugging session ends.

On IIS it ends when the worker process stops. This happens automatically after some time, depending on your application pool settings.

In Cassandra and IIS Express it will happen when the process ends *gracefully*. I wonder if they get ever called on a regular basis on those installations.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where `Application_End` was not called because there were threads running when the application was asked to stop, and because this method is only called after everything has stopped fine.

Then, I discovered `Application_Disposed`. From http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/5771721/ :

> Application_Disposed: Fired just before an application is destroyed. This is the ideal location for cleaning up previously used resources.

Comment: The article is wrong (at least for IIS 8). Application_Disposed is called per every instance of application class while Application_End is called once per whole AppDomain. _source: own experience_

Comment: It seems debugging on IIS Express Application_Disposed gets called every 10-30 sec